# Prove $(U_1 + U_2) \cap (U_2 + U_3) \cap (U_3 + U_1) = (U_1+U_2) \cap U_3 + (U_1 + U_3) \cap U_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that for any three subspaces $U_1, U_2, U_3$. $(U_1 + U_2) \cap (U_2 + U_3) \cap (U_3 + U_1) = (U_1+U_2) \cap U_3 + (U_1 + U_3) \cap U_2$ is true.

I tried to prove it by definition as I did in the begging of my calculus course with different equalities with sets. However, nothing became more clear after these attempts.

Maybe some other ways to prove it are possible? Of course, we can try to find basis somehow and see that one is the same as another. But it seems even worse as we don’t know anything about their structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use two sided inclusion:

Let $x$ be element of the left hand side, so there are $a_i,b_i,c_i\in U_i$ such that
$$x\ =\ a_1+a_2\ =\ b_2+b_3\ =\ c_1+c_3\,.$$
Then $b_3\ =\ x-b_2\ =\ a_1+a_2-b_2\ \in (U_1+U_2)\cap U_3$, and similarly
$b_2=c_1+c_3-b_3\ \in (U_1+U_3)\cap U_2$.

For the other direction, let $x$ be an element of the right hand side, so that $x=b_2+b_3$ with $b_2\in (U_1+U_3)\cap U_2$ and $b_3\in (U_1+U_2)\cap U_3$, then we already see that $x\in (U_2+U_3)$.
But, as $b_2\in U_1+U_3$ and clearly $b_3\in U_3\subseteq U_1+U_3$, we also get $x=b_2+b_3\in (U_1+U_3)$ and similarly $x\in (U_1+U_2)$.